# How do I get a div to fill the width regardless if the browser window is shrunk?

Tags: html, css

I can't get my divs to fill up the entire with of the browser it will only fill up the width of the screen you see. It does not fill the entire width if you scroll the browser when shrunk. On the surface it looks like its working but if you shrink the browser and move the scroll bar to the right you can clearly see it is flawed. I have tried min width, width 100% , margin and padding 0

http://jsfiddle.net/BdQvp/159/

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0;background-color:#00F;}
    div {margin: 0; padding: 0;background-color:#F00;}
    span{font-size:30px;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>hello</div>
hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello.<br><br><br><br>
    <span>
watch as u shrink the window and move the scroll bar to the right that the red div stops and does not fill the width of the browser only the width of the screen............ <br>                                   <br>
    How do I get the red div to fill the width regardless if the browser window is shrunk?
    </span>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Well, a simple way would be to `overflow:hidden` your body... but i suppose it's not exactly what you want :D

Comment: It's really not clear to me what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i edited it to make it clearer

Comment: What I am trying to understand is **"what problem are you trying to solve"** or are you **"just asking"**.

Comment: the red div is NOT the width of the content like it should be

Comment: watch as u shrink the window and move the scroll bar to the right that the red div stops and does not fill the width of the browser only the width of the screen............ <br>                                   <br>
    How do I get the red div to fill the width regardless if the browser window is shrunk?

Comment: the red div should be 100% of the content even when the browser is shrunk

Comment: You can't... the red div is 100% wide of the containing block. You can't make it extend into an overflow area.. That's not the way [**width**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/width) works. You have an extreme example which would not occur in real life. If you can show us the **actual** issue, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the purple div is wider then the screen, so it adds the bottom scroll bar. One way to fix this is to wrap all the text in a block element (In this case i used a `<p>`), and give it a width of 100%.

### CSS:

```
p{
    width:100%;
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

### HTML:

```
<p>
hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello.
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span>
        watch as u shrink the window and move the scrollbar to the right that the red div stops and does not fill the witdh of the browser only the width of the screen............ 
        <br>
        <br>
        How do I get the red div to fill the width regarless if the brower window is shrunk?
    </span>
</p>
```

## [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BdQvp/166/)

Comment: the red div still does not fill the width of the content it gets cut off.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/jgd5r1jk1/  see how the red div does not stretch to match the content

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/2nrLbbLu/

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #00F;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #F00;
}
span {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Though I feel this isn't a great solution, just a solution based on the existing code you already had to work with.

Additionally, you could use:

```
word-break: break-word;
```

In your body tag too.

Comment: And how would one be able to see the content that extends beyond the right side without the scrollbar?

Comment: You can't. You would need word-break: break-word; to do that.